# Error when I raised the PropertyChanged event on INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm getting an error when I run this code on the physical phone, but not on the emulator:

> System.ArgumentException "The parameter is incorrect"

when I use the following code. This is a custom type I created to allow me to easily create types that can Bind to the View.

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
```

This worked perfectly fine until I made it Generic:

```
public class BindableType<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private T _value;
    private T _previousValue;

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _previousValue = _value;
            _value = value;
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }
        }
    }

    public T PreviousValue
    {
        get { return _previousValue; }
    }
}
```

Here is the binding code:

Here is the stack trace:

> at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)    at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj,
>   DependencyProperty property, Double d)    at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh,
>   DependencyProperty property, Object obj)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object value)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty
>   property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty
>   property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry,
>   ValueOperation operation)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty
>   dp)    at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.RefreshExpression()
>   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourcePropertyChanged(PropertyPathListener
>   sender, PropertyPathChangedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.RaisePropertyPathStepChanged(PropertyPathStep
>   source)    at
>   System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.RaisePropertyPathStepChanged(PropertyListener
>   source)    at
>   System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.SourcePropertyChanged(Object
>   sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.WeakPropertyChangedListener.PropertyChangedCallback(Object
>   sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)    at
>   RoadCast.Model.BindableType`1.set_Value(Double value)    at
>   RoadCast.Default.locationHelper_PositionChangedMinor(Object sender,
>   GeoPositionChangedEventArgs`1 args)    at
>   RoadCast.Core.LocationHelper.watcher_PositionChanged(Object sender,
>   GeoPositionChangedEventArgs`1 e)    at
>   System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object
>   _)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo
>   rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly
>   caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)    at
>   System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority
>   priority)    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object
>   context)    at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[]
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
>   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr
>   pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam&
>   pResult)

UPDATE:  Renaming the Property to "InternalValue" fixed this for me.

Comment: Please, post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I would try calling it something different than Value but that is just a reach.

Comment: Seems to work fine. `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty.Value}"/>` where `MyProperty` is of type `BindableType<string>`

Comment: @ElleryFamilia - just a comment - but you do not check if value = value (i.e. the property isn't actually changing). You are also not Notifying that PreviousValue has changed.

Comment: Folks, I update the question. Please note that the Exception only happens when running the code on the device, but not on the emulator.

Comment: @BalamBalam That was it! I renamed the Property to "InternalValue" and it works fine now. That's really strange behavior.. especially since it only happened once I made the type generic.

Comment: @willmel Thanks for your comment. I actually don't want a notification when PreviousValue changes, but I should certainly check if value = value.

Comment: UPDATE: While changing the name of the Property stopped the runtime exception, the PropertyChanged now had a null value. Mark W's answer below resolved this issue completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize your PropertyChanged to this:

```
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

Comment: @ElleryFamilia There's a big post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c (search for Avoid checking for null event handlers) that talks about how this is a bad idea.